# Build image in html

Tags: html, css

I need to build some image in my html. I can't use css styles, because I want to use this markup for email mailing. 
I need to build image like that:

[image]

I need doing it in HTML because I have some text that might be change. 
Now I have this markup:

```
<td>
    <div style="background-color: white;width: 702px;height:100px;border-radius:20px;  ">
        <img style="float: left;margin-top: 2%;margin-left: 2%;" src="rux.png" alt="" />

        <p style="color:lightslategrey;font-size: 2em;padding-left: 5%;display: inline-block;">ДАЙДЖЕСТ НОВИН</p>
    </div>
</td>
```

but I don't know how to add shape like right(orange one) and grey shape in bottom.
Appreciate for all kind of help.

Comment: You can use CSS in emails - what is the reason that you're avoiding this? Building this in HTML is going to be messy, difficult and not very cross-browser/client compatible.

Comment: Why not use, say, an image?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan He said the text could change - let's assume this would be dynamic in this context. If not, then yes and image would be best!

Comment: Certainly we have the technology to serve dynamic images? I was doing that back in the 90s...

Comment: Content of `style` tags **is CSS**. If you mean your customers email clients only support **inline** CSS then you'll have to use tables; it's unlikely that such an ancient client will support floating elements.

Comment: Yeah, the best way to go is to serve a dynamic image server-side.

Comment: Email clients like Outlook will uninstall themselves when encountering CSS3 styles which would be required to create such a thing client-side! Go with what @MikeMcCaughan said. Serve the image.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan If the OP has the infrastructure available to them to implement dynamic images that would be an ideal solution.

Comment: I must to use inline css styles. Maybe someone have imagine how I can do that with tables?

Comment: You can try making a svg, or convert to [data:uri](https://dopiaza.org/tools/datauri/index.php)